# Format dates in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, formatting

I have a dataframe in which dates stored in one column. But the problem is some values are stored using %d-%m-%y format while the others stored in %Y-%m-%d format. I want all the values in one format, so I tried

```
df$dateCol= as.Date(df$dateCol, format = "%d-%m-%y")
```

But it didn't format the values properly

What's the correct way to solve this issue?

Comment: You can use multiple formats in `as.Date()`, but *lubridate* makes handling multiples a little easier.

Comment: The `Date` class (like the datetime classes) only has one way of storing values; it's `format` parameter is for converting to that format—not for how it'll be stored once it's there. You can output them as strings of any format if you like, but it's best to just put everything into the same class and work with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a simple `ifelse()` checking where the dashes `-` are:

```
x <- c("07-06-2016","2016-06-07","2015-01-01")
as.Date(x, ifelse(substr(x, 5, 5)=="-", "%Y-%m-%d", "%d-%m-%Y") )
#[1] "2016-06-07" "2016-06-07" "2015-01-01"
```